# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed in matrix.cpp line 522

Tags: c++, opencv

I was trying to run a piece of code for testing, so far I have a problem like this:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in Mat, file /home/diji/opencv-3.2.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 522
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>     what():  /home/diji/opencv-3.2.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:522: error: (-215) 0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows in function Mat

I have pasted the code below

```
int main() {

    // Set-Up
    int houghVote = 200;
    string arg = "";

    // Set up windows
    bool showOriginal = 1;
    bool showCanny = 1;
    bool showHough = 1;
    bool showHoughP = 1;

    // Capture Input
    string window_name = "Processed Video";
    namedWindow(window_name, CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO); //resizable window;
    VideoCapture capture("/home/lane-detection-master/test_video/mm.mp4");

    if (!capture.isOpened())  // Caputure Camera
    {capture.open(atoi(arg.c_str()));}



    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, 100000); //start the video at 100 seconds in

    double dWidth = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //get the width of frames of the video
    double dHeight = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); //get the height of frames of the video

    std::cout << "Frame Size = " << dWidth << "x" << dHeight << std::endl;
    Size frameSize(static_cast<int>(dWidth), static_cast<int>(dHeight));

    // Encode resulting video
    // VideoWriter oVideoWriter ("LaneDetection.avi", CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1'), 20, frameSize, true);

    // Process Frame
    Mat image;
    double frameItr = 0;
    image = imread(arg);
    int crestCount = 0, frameSkip = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        // capture on intervals to make vid smoother
        capture >> image;
        frameItr += 100;
        capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, frameItr);

        if (image.empty())
            break;

        Mat gray;
        cvtColor(image,gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);
        vector<string> codes;
        Mat corners;
        //findDataMatrix(gray, codes, corners);
        //drawDataMatrixCodes(image, codes, corners);

        // ROI
        // optimized? -=> yes
        int top = 0;
        int left = 0;
        int width = 800;
        int height = 600;

        Rect roi(left,top,width,height);
        Mat imgROI = image(roi);
        Scalar val = Scalar(0, 0, 0);
        copyMakeBorder(imgROI, imgROI, 2, 2, 2, 2, BORDER_CONSTANT, val);

        // Display the image
        if(showOriginal) {
            namedWindow("Original Image");
            imshow("Original Image",imgROI);
            imwrite("original.bmp", imgROI);
        }

        // Canny algorithm
        Mat contours;
        Canny(imgROI,contours,100,200);
        Mat contoursInv;
        threshold(contours,contoursInv,128,255,THRESH_BINARY_INV);

        // Display Canny image
        if(showCanny) {
            namedWindow("Contours");
            imshow("Contours1",contours); // use contoursInv for white
            imwrite("contours.bmp", contours);
        }

        /*
         Hough tranform for line detection with feedback
         Increase by 25 for the next frame if we found some lines.
         This is so we don't miss other lines that may crop up in the next frame
         but at the same time we don't want to start the feed back loop from scratch.
         */
        std::vector<Vec2f> lines;
        if (houghVote < 1 or lines.size() > 2) { // we lost all lines. reset
            houghVote = 300;
        }
        else{ houghVote += 25;}
        while(lines.size() < 4 && houghVote > 0){
            HoughLines(contours,lines,1,PI/180, houghVote);
            houghVote -= 5;
        }
        std::cout << houghVote << "\n";
        Mat result(imgROI.size(),CV_8U,Scalar(255));
        imgROI.copyTo(result);

        // Draw the lines
        std::vector<Vec2f>::const_iterator it= lines.begin();
        Mat hough(imgROI.size(),CV_8U,Scalar(0));
        while (it!=lines.end()) {

            float rho= (*it)[0];   // first element is distance rho
            float theta= (*it)[1]; // second element is angle theta

            if ( (theta > 0.09 && theta < 1.48) || (theta < 3.14 && theta > 1.66) ) { // filter to remove vertical and horizontal lines

                // point of intersection of the line with first row
                Point pt1(rho/cos(theta),0);
                // point of intersection of the line with last row
                Point pt2((rho-result.rows*sin(theta))/cos(theta),result.rows);
                // draw a line: Color = Scalar(R, G, B), thickness
                line( result, pt1, pt2, Scalar(255,255,255), 1);
                line( hough, pt1, pt2, Scalar(255,255,255), 1);
            }

            //std::cout << "line: (" << rho << "," << theta << ")\n";
            ++it;
        }

        // Display the detected line image
        if(showHough){
            namedWindow("Detected Lines with Hough");
            imshow("Detected Lines with Hough",result);
            imwrite("hough.bmp", result);
        }

        // Create LineFinder instance
        LineFinder ld;

        // Set probabilistic Hough parameters
        ld.setLineLengthAndGap(10,60); // min accepted length and gap
        ld.setMinVote(15); // sit > 3 to get rid of "spiderweb"

        // Detect lines
        std::vector<Vec4i> li= ld.findLines(contours);
        Mat houghP(imgROI.size(),CV_8U,Scalar(0));
        ld.setShift(0,0);
        ld.drawDetectedLines(houghP);
        std::cout << "First Hough" << "\n";

        if(showHoughP){
            namedWindow("Detected Lines with HoughP");
            imshow("Detected Lines with HoughP", houghP);
            imwrite("houghP.bmp", houghP);
        }

        // bitwise AND of the two hough images
        bitwise_and(houghP,hough,houghP);
        Mat houghPinv(imgROI.size(),CV_8U,Scalar(0));
        Mat dst(imgROI.size(),CV_8U,Scalar(0));
        threshold(houghP,houghPinv,150,255,THRESH_BINARY_INV); // threshold and invert to black lines

        if(showHoughP){
            namedWindow("Detected Lines with Bitwise");
            imshow("Detected Lines with Bitwise", houghP);
        }


        Canny(houghPinv,contours,100,350);
        li = ld.findLines(contours);


        // Test to draw point
        //ld.drawPoint(image, Point(320,130));

        // Set probabilistic Hough parameters
        // more strict than above HoughP
        ld.setLineLengthAndGap(5,2);
        ld.setMinVote(1);
        ld.setShift(top, left);

        // draw point on image where line intersection occurs
        int yShift = 25;
        int allowableFrameSkip = 5;
        ld.drawDetectedLines(image);
        cv::Point iPnt = ld.drawIntersectionPunto(image, 2);

        // track hill crest
        int gap = 20;
        cv::Point lptl(0, image.rows / 2 + yShift);
        cv::Point lptr(gap, image.rows / 2 + yShift);
        line(image, lptl, lptr, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 1);// left mid line

        cv::Point rptl(image.cols - gap, image.rows / 2 + yShift);
        cv::Point rptr(image.cols, image.rows / 2 + yShift);
        line(image, rptl, rptr, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 1);// right mid line

        cv::Point ulpt(0, image.rows / 2 - 50 + yShift);
        cv::Point urpt(image.cols, image.rows / 2 - 50 + yShift);

        bool hillCrestFound = (iPnt.y < (image.rows / 2 + yShift)) && (iPnt.y > (image.rows / 2 - 50 + yShift));
        if(hillCrestFound) {
            crestCount++;
            frameSkip = 0;
        } else if(crestCount != 0 && frameSkip < allowableFrameSkip)
            frameSkip++;
        else {
            crestCount = 0;
            frameSkip = 0;
        }

        cv::Point txtPt(image.cols / 2 - 31, image.rows / 2 - 140);
        if(crestCount > 3)
            putText(image, "tracking", txtPt, FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2, 8);

        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << "Lines Segments: " << lines.size();

        putText(image, stream.str(), Point(10,image.rows-10), 1, 0.8, Scalar(0,255,0),0);
        imshow(window_name, image);
        imwrite("processed.bmp", image);

        //  oVideoWriter.write(image); //writer the frame into the file

        char key = (char) waitKey(10);
        lines.clear();
    }
}
```

I assume there is a conflict with the matrix.cpp file, however can't diagnose what exactly the problem is. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: _I assume there is a conflict with the matrix.cpp file, however can't diagnose what exactly the problem is._ Why are you even trying to guess what the problem is? Step through your code, with a debugger, and find out, the exact source of the problem!

Comment: This error message is telling you that the dimensions on your mat objects do not match.

Comment: that's a lot of code for one function, which line does the error occur in (title says 522, but that's not very helpful, please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))?

Answer (score 1):

This occurs when the `Mat` is not loaded or you are trying to access the wrong value of height or width (eg. negative values). Those are the common reasons.

In your code

```
    int width = 800;
    int height = 600;

    Rect roi(left,top,width,height);
```

Here, you are trying to crop this rectangle from the captured image. But the capture image's width or height can be less than that. The rectangle here must be inclusive in the image.

However, this is a long source code. there are more cases where the code can fail. So use some debugging to find where the problem occurs.

**NOTE** `I assume there is a conflict with the matrix.cpp file`, this is very much unlikely, so assume that the matrix.cpp file has no conflict.